# Align text vertically in box in Dia?

Tags: dia

In Dia, I can add a flowchart box, then add text inside it, and then format the text using properties:

[image: dia]

I can align the text horizontally (i.e. left, center, right) inside the box - but i don't see an option to align the text vertically (i.e. top, center, bottom) inside the box. This is on Dia 0.97.2.

Is there a way to align text vertically in a flow/text box in Dia?

EDIT: It can somewhat be achieved by adding carriage return/line feed/Enters either before or after the text (and also controlling the text padding) - but I was wandering if there was a built in function...

Comment: For me this is the feature I miss most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grouping a Box- and Text object after custom alignment, is that a solution you already think about. Or using a different Box object like a [UML Class](http://dia-installer.de/doc/en/objects-chapter.html) object, it seems you can add text in the top, middle and button of that box, see 4.2.7 in the provided link.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Hölderlin - that makes sense; cheers!